# Chrome packaged app - find out if running in kiosk-mode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I'm creating an application that can be run both in kiosk mode and normally (like, open from Chrome browser) but certain features should only be allowed to run in kiosk mode. Is there a way I can find out if it's running in kiosk-mode or in normal fullscreen/windowed-mode?

Here's a snippet from my manifest.json if it's any help

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "kiosk_enabled": true,
    "kiosk_only": false
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation:

To determine whether the app is being run in a regular session or Single App Kiosk Mode, you can inspect the isKioskSession boolean that's included in the launchData object from the [app.runtime.onLaunched](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_runtime#event-onLaunched) event.

So:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(launchData) {
    launchData.isKioskSession; //true or false
});
```

Comment: node-webkit? This is not anything I'm using as far as I know of. Does it extend the normal Window-object to add that flag?

Comment: Whups, my bad. Would help if I read the question properly. :)

Comment: Updated with relevant answer.

Comment: This works like a charm! I have no idea how I missed that in the documentation!

Comment: For me on mac this is not working in regualar javascript chrome

Comment: How it can be implemented for PWA apps? Google recently deprecated ChromeApp support.